# Get xmllint xpath nodes to arrays

Tags: arrays, xml, xpath, nmap, xmllint

I have NMAP-output xml-file like this:

```
<host><status state="down" reason="no-response" reason_ttl="0"/>
<address addr="192.168.1.1" addrtype="ipv4"/>
</host>
<taskbegin task="SYN Stealth Scan" time="1457545799"/>
<taskend task="SYN Stealth Scan" time="1457545841" extrainfo="1600 total ports"/>
<host starttime="1457545794" endtime="1457545839"><status state="up" reason="echo-reply" reason_ttl="243"/>
<address addr="192.168.1.2" addrtype="ipv4"/>
<hostnames>
<hostname name="192-168-1-2.liibalaaba.com" type="PTR"/>
</hostnames>
<ports><extraports state="closed" count="100">
<extrareasons reason="resets" count="100"/>
</extraports>
</ports>
<times srtt="6454" rttvar="163" to="100000"/>
</host>
<host starttime="1457545794" endtime="1457545837"><status state="up" reason="echo-reply" reason_ttl="51"/>
<address addr="192.168.1.3" addrtype="ipv4"/>
<hostnames>
<hostname name="192-168-1-3.liibalaaba.com" type="PTR"/>
</hostnames>
<ports><extraports state="filtered" count="98">
<extrareasons reason="no-responses" count="98"/>
</extraports>
<port protocol="tcp" portid="80"></port>
<port protocol="tcp" portid="443"></port>
</ports>
<times srtt="6378" rttvar="191" to="100000"/>
</host>
<host starttime="1457545794" endtime="1457545841"><status state="up" reason="echo-reply" reason_ttl="115"/>
<address addr="192.168.1.4" addrtype="ipv4"/>
<hostnames>
<hostname name="192-168-1-4.liibalaaba.com" type="PTR"/>
</hostnames>
<ports><extraports state="filtered" count="97">
<extrareasons reason="no-responses" count="97"/>
</extraports>
<port protocol="tcp" portid="80"></port>
<port protocol="tcp" portid="81"></port>
<port protocol="tcp" portid="443"></port>
</ports>
<times srtt="6417" rttvar="113" to="100000"/>
</host>
```

How I can put only the hosts that have open ports to an array and then to readable format? (Do I even need an array?)

Something like this:

```
address:192.168.1.3 [0,0]
open ports:80 [0,1], 443 [0,2]
address:192.168.1.4 [1,0]
open ports:80[1,1], 81 [1,2], 443 [1,3]
```

Now i'm using xmllint xpath combo, but it just splits out every address that has open ports to same line:

```
`xmllint --xpath "//*[local-name()='host']/*[local-name()='address']/@addr | //*[local-name()='ports']/*[local-name()='port']/@portid" nmap-scan.xml >    result.txt`
```

Thanks for help!

Comment: What are the numbers that you are trying to put in square brackets besides address or ports?

Comment: Are you ok with the output format say `address: port1, port2`?

Comment: @Rao Those numbers in brackets is just to show those fictive places in array. Just to demonstrate, nothing more. That `address: port1, port2` format would be ok.